# How to add icomoon icons to canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

How to add icons from icomoons to canvas by fillText() method?

```
ctx.font = '10px';
ctx.fillText = 'white';
ctx.fillText(??);
```

Answer (score 2):

Mostlikely you will have to link your icon package at first.
I believe then you would call the icon like so:

```
ctx.fillText('\uF047');
```

The F047 shoudl be replaced with your icon code.
You might have to prefix your character code with the Unicode prefix (\u)